# Function definition in Maxima CAS

Tags: lisp, copy-paste, maxima

I have a function :

```
GiveBTree(z, depthMax):=block(

    [ zz, t1, t2, tmp],
    zz :[], 
    t1 :[z], 
    t2 :[], 
    tmp  :[], 
        
    for depth : 1 thru depthMax step 1 do (
        
        
        for z in t1 do (
            tmp : Give2Preimages(z),
            zz : append(tmp, zz),
            t2 : append(tmp, t2)
            
        )
        
        tmp:[],
        t1:t2 
        
    ),
    
    zz:flatten(zz),     
    return (zz)
)$
```

When I put it in the Maxima I have :

```
Maxima 5.43.2 http://maxima.sourceforge.net
using Lisp GNU Common Lisp (GCL) GCL 2.6.12
Distributed under the GNU Public License. See the file COPYING.
Dedicated to the memory of William Schelter.
The function bug_report() provides bug reporting information.
(%i1) GiveBTree(z, depthMax):=block(
[ zz, t1, t2, tmp],
zz :[], 
t1 :[z], 
t2 :[], 
tmp  :[], 

Display all 2857 possibilities? (y or n)
                                       JACOBI_CD
!                                      JACOBI_CN
!!                                     JACOBI_CS
#                                      JACOBI_DC
$                                      JACOBI_DN
```

The problem seems to start after tmp.

So I checked:

- googled : maxima cas "Display all"
- index of Maxima functions
- describe(tmp)

What is wrong with this definition ?

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with `tmp`. My first guess is that when you enter a blank line, somehow the word completion feature of readline (which handles input line editing for GCL) is triggered. I have two suggestions. (1) Put the program into a file, let's say `GiveBTree.mac`, and then say, in Maxima, `load("GiveBTree.mac");`. (2) Ensure that you have an up-to-date version of Maxima, built with some Lisp other than GCL. Versions of Maxima in package managers such as apt-get are typically out of date. Hope this helps.

Comment: https://pl.wikibooks.org/wiki/Maxima#Problemy

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dynamical_plane_with_branched_periodic_external_ray_0_for_map_f(z)_%3D_z*z_%2B_0.35.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the steps as Robert Dodier said:

```
(%i2) load("g.mac");
(%o2)                                g.mac
```

So the problem was caused by "copy and paste".